Touchpad problems after upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04
What the title says. My touchpad was working fine until after an upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04, when it started acting strange.
What's strange? Clicking started working differently and fine mouse movements became more difficult to do.
Right now the following command gets it to work as a workaround after every boot: sudo rmmod i2c_hid_acpi && sudo modprobe i2c_hid_acpi
From here: https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/1cm5up8/thinkpad_z13_gen_2_touchpad_not_working_on_ubuntu/
However, I would like to fix the underlying issue if possible; typing remains a pain because the touchpad isn't disabled when typing after that workaround.
I tried creating a new account on my system but that account had the same issues that my normal user account does, so it doesn't appear to be user specific settings.
The relevant results of xinput --list are:

⎡ Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer
(2)] ⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse                 id=14   [slave
pointer  (2)] ⎜   ↳ FTCS1000:01 2808:0102 Mouse
id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)] ⎜   ↳ FTCS1000:01 2808:0102 Touchpad
id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]

If that helps.
Any advice or recommendations would be welcome.
